# join based on condition

Tags: sql, join

I have a column A.name  in table A as below

```
+--------+
| A.name |
+--------+
| aaa    |
| bbb    |
| ccc    |
| ddd    |
| eee    |
+--------+
```

and I have a column B.full_name in table B with large amount of data as below

```
+--------------+
| B.full_name  |
+--------------+
| aaaaaaa      |
| bbbbefe      |
| ddddef       |
| eee          |
| feed         |
| kccc         |
+--------------+
```

now I would like to find the number of names in A.name,if B.full_name contains value in A.name
the pseudo is as below

```
select name,count(name) 
from (
select name
from table_A a 
left outer join 
(select 
    full_name
from table_B) b
on a.name LIKE '%'+ b.full_name +'%') aa 
group by name
```

join based on like operator is not working on my RDBMS.

Any suggestion ? thanks a lot

Comment: What is your RDBMS?  Your join condition looks right to me.

Comment: Just to get ride of "+" in a.name LIKE "%b.full_name%"

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the RDBMS is developed by my own company, and it seems it only support  join on  =  not join on like

Comment: Well then this isn't going to go well because you need some pattern matching to join.

Comment: @DanielE.  Join with like won't work on my RDMS, I'm wondering if there is other way to get the same goal, thanks

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen any idea on how to use pattern matching?

Comment: Yes, use `LIKE`.

Comment: What you need to do is design your database properly. If two fields are going to be used to find records in both tables they need to contain data in the same format.  There is no way to get correct answers when pattern matching on this sort of data.  For instance John Ho could match to Steve Hovermale or Judith Johnson. The only choice you have is to correctly store the names the exact same way in both tables.

Comment: I posted my solution and I think your condition is not right. it has to be b.full_name LIKE '%' + a.name + '%'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't you extract the data to eg. a C# or java program or something and do the matching  using indexOfFunction in string class and then push the data back to the database?

Answer (score 0):

The query should be like this :

```
select name, count(name) 
from (
    select name
    from table_A a 
    left outer join 
        (
        select full_name
        from table_B
        ) b
    on b.full_name LIKE '%' + a.name + '%'
    ) aa 
group by name
```

The joining relation `on a.name LIKE '%'+ b.full_name +'%'` is changed to **`on b.full_name LIKE '%' + a.name + '%'`**

Comment: The OP does not have access to `LIKE` in join conditions.

Comment: Hi, Md. Thanks for your reply, but , the thing is my RDMS doesn't support join on like, it only support join on equal , so I'm wondering if there is any other method to get the same goal, thanks

Comment: Don't know what other thing can be done in your `RDBMS` If possible, you can check the index of `a.name` in `b.full_name` to know the existence.

Comment: I agree.  I don't know what sort of database this is.

Comment: I'm using this RDBMS： MaxCompute

Answer (score 0):

You need to cross join two tables and find the rows that meet the criteria.

```
select a.name, count(*) 
from from table_A a 
    left outer join  table_B b
Where b.full_name LIKE '%' + a.name + '%'       
group by name
```